# Determine What Line a Function Was Executed From

Tags: php

I'm trying to build an error class and a lot of error classes I've looked at in the past use **FILE** and **LINE** to show where the error occurred, but they use them in the function so they're always the same, which is highly useless information. Aside from sending an array of containing **FILE** and **LINE** with every function (which would get to be quite a pain), I can't think of or find anything else. Is there a good way or a function out there to determine the correct line number and file that the function was being executed from?

Example:

```
<?php
// file1.php
dosomething(false);
?>

<?php
// file2.php
function dosomething($input) {
    if ($input === false) die("Error at Line (line) in File (file)");
}
?>
```

The function would die with the message "Error at Line 3 in File */file1.php*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose a solution could be to use [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).

The given example gets a backtrace like this :

```
array(2) {
[0]=>
array(4) {
    ["file"] => string(10) "/tmp/a.php"
    ["line"] => int(10)
    ["function"] => string(6) "a_test"
    ["args"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0] => &string(6) "friend"
    }
}
[1]=>
array(4) {
    ["file"] => string(10) "/tmp/b.php"
    ["line"] => int(2)
    ["args"] =>
    array(1) {
      [0] => string(10) "/tmp/a.php"
    }
    ["function"] => string(12) "include_once"
  }
}
```

So, should include what you want ;-)

And if you just want to output the trace *(not likely)*, there is also [`debug_print_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php).

Answer (score 0):

Check set_error_handler function:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php
You may also want to look on set_exception_handler function.

Answer (score 0):

The function I'm using on my sites:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Determine what line a function was executed from</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    function linea($string1, $linea, $string2 = NULL)
    {
      $string2 = !empty($string2) ? $string2 : '';
      return $string1 . $linea . $string2;
    }
    echo linea('Error: ', __LINE__) . '<br />';
    /*
    ...
    lot of code
    ...
    */
    echo linea('Alert -> ', __LINE__, '!') . '<br />';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Outputs:

```
Error: 13
Alert -> 19!
```